# sliding form not working properly?

Tags: javascript, sliding

1) I need "open panel" and "close panel" working but it cannot work properly

2)The code is in the below link.

3)please check the link you can understood properly

http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/2jgL44c5/

```
function slide_open(){
    var a=document.getElementById("strip");
    a.setAttribute("onClick","close_panel()");
    close_panel();
    }
function open_panel(){
    var right_position= 0;
    var slide_form=document.getElementById('contact_form');
    if(parseInt(slide_form.style.right) < right_position){
        slide_form.style.right=parseInt(slide_form.style.right) + 2 + "px";
        setTimeout(open_panel(), 1);
        }
    slide_open();
    }
function slide_close(){
    var a=document.getElementById('strip');
    a.setAttribute("onClick", "open_panel");
    open_panel();
    }
function close_panel(){
    var right_position= -200;
    var slide_form=document.getElementById('contact_form');
    if(parseInt(slide_form.style.right) > right_position){
        slide_form.style.right=parseInt(slide_form.style.right) - 2 + "px";
        setTimeout(close_panel(), 1);
        }
    slide_close();
    }
```

Comment: did you try looking at the error thrown in console? Take a look at how [addEventListener](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html) works

Comment: It might be because you're using onClick to bind the function to the div instead of addEventListener.

Comment: Seems to me you have some infinite loops. Why is `slide_close()` executing `slide_open()` and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a much simpler solution. Always try to do all you CSS styling within your CSS files, and control different states by applying and removing classes on your elements. Like so:

```
var strip = document.getElementById('strip');
var slide_form=document.getElementById('contact_form');

strip.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if (slide_form.classList.contains('open'))
        slide_form.className = slide_form.className.replace(' open', '');
    else
        slide_form.className = slide_form.className + ' open';
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ostrgard/2jgL44c5/6/).

Comment: Worth mentioning that slide_form.className == 'open' will only work if  'open' is the only class on the element, if you have other classes for styling you'll need a substring/regex match instead

Comment: i.e. class name returns a single string containing all classes

Comment: True. I'd typically go with jQuery when working with classes like this. I've updated the answer to take this into account.